# Linkit one does not work with NFC Module V3

Tags: nfc

I try the NFC sample code, but it is not working. 
When I put my phone above the NFC board, my phone NFC APP can't not detect any imformation even if a tag id. 
How could I do ? The following messages are from my console port.

```
----------------- nfc ndef push url --------------------
Get Version
Read Ack
 0 0 FF 0 FF 0Read response:  0 0 FF 6 FA D5 3 32 1 6 7 E8 0
Get Version
Read Ack
 0 0 FF 0 FF 0Read response:  0 0 FF 6 FA D5 3 32 1 6 7 E8 0
Found chip PN532
Firmware ver. 1.6
Supports 7
Read Ack
Read ACK Timeout
Read response: 
---------------- LOOP ----------------------

Read Ack
Read ACK Timeout
Read response: 
SNEP Sever:Blocking wait response.
Read response:
```

The sample code is from https://github.com/elechouse/NFC_Module_DEV.
By the way, my cell phone is HTC M8.